# Is there any way to specify a maximum time for each state in UPPAAL global?

Tags: uppaal

I want to specify that all state shouldn't be longer than a specified time. I can do it by specifying it state by state, but human can forget one. I need a global solution. I mean something like 'max time in each state' property.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more process with a single location and put all your global invariants over there.

You can also have an array of bounds, e.g:

declarations:

```
typedef int[1,5] id_t;
clock c[id_t]; // clocks
const int b[id_t] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }; // bounds
```

invariant:

```
forall(i:id_t) c[i]<=b[i]
```